# How to use switchmap to avoid nested subscriptions in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, switchmap

I read a lot about switchmap and its purpose but I did not see a lot of examples when it comes to subscribing to the new data.
So I use a nested subscription in my Angular project and I wanted to ask you how to use switchmap properly in my example to understand the concept better.

Here my nested subscription:

```
this.sharedSrv.postDetail.subscribe(async post => {
        if(post) {
            this.hasPost = true;
            this.post = post;
        }
        console.log(post);
        this.viewedMainComment = null;
        this.viewedSubComments = [];
        this.userSrv.getUserAsObservable().subscribe(user => {
            if(user){
                if(this.post.user.id == user.id) this.isOwnPost = true; 
                this.user = user;
                this.postsSrv.getPostInteraction(this.user.id, this.post.id, this.post.user.id).subscribe(interaction => {
                    this.hasSubscribed = interaction["hasSubscribed"];
                    this.wasLiked = interaction["wasLiked"];
                    this.wasDisliked = interaction["wasDisliked"];
                    this.hasSaved = interaction["hasSaved"];
                });
                console.log(user);
                this.isLoggedIn = true
            } else {
                this.isLoggedIn = false;
            }
        })
})
```

How would I use switchmap correctly here?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: While the question is valid, it is the preferred practice to remove all the unrelated statements from the code, as they obfuscate the essentials. In your case, about 2/3 of the code can be removed from the question.

Comment: @Avius I am sorry, I did not remove code so that you see what I am trying here and maybe you see other mistakes I do and correct me.

Comment: Fair enough and no problem (no need to apologise), just something to keep in mind in the future :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple things to notice here

1. Looks like the outer observable `this.sharedSrv.postDetail` and `this.userSrv.getUserAsObservable()` are unrelated. In that case you could also use RxJS `forkJoin` to trigger the observables in parallel. Since you've asked for `switchMap`, you could try the following

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.sharedSrv.postDetail.pipe(
  switchMap(post => {
    if (post) {
      this.hasPost = true;
      this.post = post;
    }
    console.log(post);
    this.viewedMainComment = null;
    this.viewedSubComments = [];
    return this.userSrv.getUserAsObservable();
  }),
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      if (this.post.user.id == user.id) this.isOwnPost = true;
      this.user = user;
      console.log(user);
      return this.postsSrv.getPostInteraction(this.user.id, this.post.id, this.post.user.id);
    }
    return of(null); // <-- emit `null` if `user` is undefined
  })
).subscribe(
  interaction => {
    if(!!interaction) { // <-- only proceed if `interaction` is defined
      this.hasSubscribed = interaction["hasSubscribed"];
      this.wasLiked = interaction["wasLiked"];
      this.wasDisliked = interaction["wasDisliked"];
      this.hasSaved = interaction["hasSaved"];
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
    } else { // <-- set `isLoggedIn` to false if `user` was undefined
      this.isLoggedIn = false;
    }
  }
);
```

2. I assume you're converting the observable to a promise using `async`. First I'd recommend you not to mix observables and promises unless absolutely necessary. Second you could use RxJS `from` function to convert an observable to a promise.

```js
import { from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const obs$ = this.sharedSrv.postDetail.pipe(
  switchMap(post => {
    if (post) {
      this.hasPost = true;
      this.post = post;
    }
    console.log(post);
    this.viewedMainComment = null;
    this.viewedSubComments = [];
    return this.userSrv.getUserAsObservable();
  }),
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      if (this.post.user.id == user.id) this.isOwnPost = true;
      this.user = user;
      console.log(user);
      return this.postsSrv.getPostInteraction(this.user.id, this.post.id, this.post.user.id);
    }
    return of(null); // <-- emit `null` if `user` is undefined
  })
);

from(obs$).then(
  interaction => {
    ...
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you want:

```
this.sharedSrv.postDetail.pipe(
  switchMap(post => {
    if (post) {
      this.hasPost = true;
      this.post = post;
    }
    console.log(post);
    this.viewedMainComment = null;
    this.viewedSubComments = [];
    return this.userSrv.getUserAsObservable();
  }),
  swtichMap(user => {
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
    if (user) {
      if (this.post.user.id == user.id) this.isOwnPost = true;
      this.user = user;
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      console.log(user);
      return this.postsSrv.getPostInteraction(this.user.id, this.post.id, this.post.user.id);
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }
  }).subscribe(interaction => {
    if (!interaction) return;
    this.hasSubscribed = interaction["hasSubscribed"];
    this.wasLiked = interaction["wasLiked"];
    this.wasDisliked = interaction["wasDisliked"];
    this.hasSaved = interaction["hasSaved"];
  })
);
```

Comment: The call to `subscribe` should be after `pipe`, i.e. `.pipe(switchMap(...)).subscribe()`.

Answer (score 1):

To transform `Observables` you need to use `piping` i.e call the `pipe()` method on the observable and pass in the an `rxjs` transformation operator

Example we can transform your code to

```typescript
this.sharedSrv.postDetail.pipe(
  switchMap(post => {
    if(post) {
      this.hasPost = true;
      this.post = post;
    }
    this.viewedMainComment = null;
    this.viewedSubComments = [];
    return this.userSrv.getUserAsObservable())
  }),
  switchMap(
    user => {
      if(user) {
         if(this.post.user.id == user.id) this.isOwnPost = true; 
         this.user = user;
         return this.postsSrv.getPostInteraction(this.user.id, this.post.id, this.post.user.id)
      } else {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
        return of (null) // You need import { of } from 'rxjs'
      }
    }
  )), 
  tap( interaction => {
    if(interaction) {
      this.hasSubscribed = interaction["hasSubscribed"];
      this.wasLiked = interaction["wasLiked"];
      this.wasDisliked = interaction["wasDisliked"];
      this.hasSaved = interaction["hasSaved"];
    }
  })
  
).subscribe()
```